# Android Как реализовать режим "обучения" в приложении?

Tags: java, android

Видел в некоторых приложениях нечто вроде режима обучения:

- Основная активность немного затемнена
- Поверх выскакивают тексты, типа "Нажмите сюда" и выделяют область

Хочется такое-же реализовать.

Не подскажите куда копать?

Comment: Как вариант заюзать библиотеку onBoarding которых вагон.

Comment: @Романыч, согласен полезные библиотеки, но мне немного другое нужно. Не презентацию с описанием, а нечто вроде тура с подсказками - "сначала сделайте фото" - "теперь введите время" и т.д. и все это привязанное к интерфейсу в реальном времени.

Comment: что то типа [showcase](https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView) - таких библиотек тоже достаточно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда-то форкал библиотеку, чтоб сделать свое обучение в приложении, основывался на этом https://github.com/sjwall/MaterialTapTargetPrompt очень помогло, возможно и вам подойдет.

Также видел https://github.com/TakuSemba/Spotlight это примерно то что вы хотите

Answer (score 4):

Использовал для подобного PopupWindow (подсказка) в связке с таким классом (затенение):

```
public class OverlayView extends FrameLayout {
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    int paddings, offset;
    RectF rect;

    public OverlayView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public OverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public OverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public OverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        rect = new RectF(0, 0, 0, 0);
        //у меня почему-то идет смещение на +24 пикселя, поэтому вымерил и выставляю смещение назад вручную
        offset = (int) (-24 * getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density); 
        //padding - по вкусу
        paddings = (int) getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.paddings);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        if (bitmap == null) {
            createWindowFrame();
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    protected void createWindowFrame() {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas osCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        RectF outerRectangle = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark));
        osCanvas.drawRect(outerRectangle, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT));
        osCanvas.drawRoundRect(rect, paddings, paddings, paint);
    }

    //если надо исключить из тени 1 view
    public void setView(View v) {
        int xStart = getRelativeLeft(v);
        int yStart = getRelativeTop(v) + offset;
        int xEnd = xStart + v.getWidth();
        int yEnd = yStart + v.getHeight();
        rect = new RectF(xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd);
        createWindowFrame();
        postInvalidate();
    }

    //если надо исключить из тени 2 view (можно настроить на большее количество)
    public void setTwoView(View v1, View v2) {
        int xStart = getRelativeLeft(v1);
        int yStart = getRelativeTop(v1) + offset;
        int xEnd = xStart + v1.getWidth();
        int yEnd = yStart + v1.getHeight();

        int xStart2 = getRelativeLeft(v2);
        int yStart2 = getRelativeTop(v2) + offset;
        int xEnd2 = xStart2 + v2.getWidth();
        int yEnd2 = yStart2 + v2.getHeight();

        rect = new RectF(Math.min(xStart, xStart2), Math.min(yStart, yStart2), Math.max(xEnd, xEnd2), Math.max(yEnd, yEnd2));
        createWindowFrame();
        postInvalidate();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isInEditMode() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        bitmap = null;
    }

    private int getRelativeLeft(View myView) {
        if (myView.getParent() == myView.getRootView())
            return myView.getLeft();
        else
            return myView.getLeft() + getRelativeLeft((View) myView.getParent());
    }

    private int getRelativeTop(View myView) {
        if (myView.getParent() == myView.getRootView())
            return myView.getTop();
        else
            return myView.getTop() + getRelativeTop((View) myView.getParent());
    }

    public void reset() {
        rect = new RectF(0, 0, 0, 0);
        createWindowFrame();
        postInvalidate();
    }
}
```

Вот так сделать PopupWindow:

```
private void setPopup() {
        popup = new PopupWindow(this);
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null);
        hint = v.findViewById(R.id.hint);
        popup.setContentView(v);
        popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));    
        v.setOnClickListener(onNextClick);
}
```

Примерно так обрабатывать клики:

```
int state = -1; //текущая подсказка

private void onNextClick(View v) {
        state++;
        popup.dismiss();
        View anchor = null;
        switch (state) {
            case 0:
                setPopup();
                screen.setTwoView(views.get(PLAYER_NAME), views.get(PLAYER_HEADER));
                anchor = views.get(PLAYER_NAME);
                break;
            case 1:
                screen.setTwoView(views.get(PLAYER_ARMY), views.get(ARMY_HEADER));
                anchor = views.get(PLAYER_ARMY);
                break;
            ...
       }
       if (anchor != null) popup.showAsDropDown(anchor, 0, 10);

       if (state < hints.length) setHint(hints[state]);
}
```

В `xml` `OverlayView` добавлен последним элементом в глобальный `FrameLayout` с параметрами `match_parent`